# Android static UI is taking to much time in loading

Tags: android-layout, android

I have developed checklist app for government internal use.
It has 250 fields in different tabular format.
What is happening  is that loading of screen takes 10 second or more in 1.4 ghz quad core processor with 1 gb ram device also.
How to improve loading of static device or at least show indicator to user that user form is being load through some indicator?
Can I load static xml file with async task?
Does it improve perfomance?
IS there any option to load static UI incrementally once user scroll down?
Please note that there are no list view.
Only static view for lines and checkboxes and text views are there.

Comment: Use Traceview to find out where your problem really is, rather than just guessing. Better yet, simplify your UI. Personally, I would fire anyone who proposed putting 250 fields in a single activity.

Comment: I personally agree with @CommonsWare: You're fired! ;)

Comment: Let me try to separate UI in different fragment and attach them pragmatically as user scroll downs..

Comment: here question is whom to fire .I am leading the team.then I need to put resignation ;)

Comment: if the fields are semantically identical and displayed as a list, use a listview.

Answer (score 0):

why dont you categorize these fields and keep in different activity so it will improve performance and application structure will be good.

Comment: it is single form.So can not use that option.

Answer (score 0):

Why not make a list view that has a custom check box row layout? It'll be much faster as it only loads what's on the screen. If you hide the dividers its practically the same assuming its a vertical list.